# SQL statement result is empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a example scenario, where I have a table with 3 columns which are

feature_id
value
product

I want to get all the products where feature_id is 1 or 3 and value is "Yes". Following query in sql give me empty result set

```
SELECT * FROM product
WHERE
(feature_id = 1 AND Value = "Yes")
AND
(feature_id = 3 AND Value = "Yes")
```

Table image is also attached:

[image]

Comment: Your query is selecting all rows where feature_id is both 1 and 3 - which is obviously not possible for any single row so you are getting zero records returned

Answer (score 4):

In your current syntax feature_id needs to be both 1 and 3 at the same time, which is impossible. You need to change `AND` to `OR`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM product
WHERE
(feature_id = 1 AND value = "Yes")
OR
(feature_id = 3 AND value = "Yes")
```

Or better:

```sql
SELECT * FROM product
WHERE feature_id IN (1, 3) 
  AND value = "Yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a combination of OR and AND

```
SELECT * FROM product
WHERE
(feature_id = 1 OR feature_id = 3)   AND Value = "Yes")
```